# Float Unsigned to Float Signed - Laravel Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration

Is there a way to convert an unsigned float to a signed float ?

What i want is to save a negative value in the database

part of the current Migration looks like

```
$table->float('job_profit', 8, 2)->unsigned()->nullable();
```

tried several such as

```
$table->float('job_profit', 8, 2)->nullable();
```

and

```
$table->decimal('job_profit', 8, 2)->nullable()->change();
```

But those didn't work for me

Comment: Does removing the unsigned not already change it to signed float?

Comment: @zaster: Please Rollback() job_profit column and after run migration with `$table->float('job_profit', 8, 2)->nullable();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$table->float('job_profit', 8, 2)->unsigned(false)->nullable()->change();
```

The only downside is that it replaces `8,2` with the default precision.